# Adding style on div on keyboard focus

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how can I add style = display:block on div.sub_menu on keyboard focus.
Right now I can only access a tag but I'm not sure how to get in to div sub_menu.
The examples I have seen has no  before  for dropdown

https://blog.hubspot.com/website/accessible-drop-down-menus

Below is my html and javascript code:

```js
var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('li.dir');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(menuItems, function(el, i) {
  el.querySelector('a').addEventListener("focus", function(event) {
    if (this.parentNode.className == "dir") {
      this.parentNode.className = "dir menu_hover";
      this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', "true");
    } else {
      this.parentNode.className = "dir";
      this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', "false");
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="primary">
  <li class="dir current">
    <a href="" title="Home" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Home</span></a>
    <div class="sub_menu">
      <ul class="sub_sub_menu ">
        <li class=" ">
          <a href="" title="Test"><span>Test Page</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dir ">
    <a href="" title="Our Products" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Our Products</span></a>
    <div class="sub_menu">
      <ul class="sub_sub_menu ">
        <li class=" ">
          <a href="" title="Test Products"><span>Test Products</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class=" ">
    <a href="" title="News"><span>News</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you!

Comment: `:focus-visible` pseudo-class might be helpful. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus-visible/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is "focusin" and "focusout" that you would need to toggle classes such as in a menu structure to open/close as you want.  See below, when home is focused, the `<a>` item under "sub_sub_menu" is given `display: block;` by adding the class `.expanded` to it.  When focus is removed the classes are toggled off in the `focusout` event listener.

```js
var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('li.dir');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(menuItems, function(el, i) {

  el.querySelector('a').addEventListener('focusin', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.parentNode.className = "dir menu_hover";
    this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', "true");
    el.querySelector('div > ul > li > a').className = "expanded";
  });

  el.querySelector('a').addEventListener('focusout', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.parentNode.className = "dir";
    this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', "false");
    el.querySelector('div > ul > li > a').className = "";
  });

});
```

```css
.expanded {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="primary">
  <li class="dir current">
    <a href="" title="Home" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Home</span></a>
    <div class="sub_menu">
      <ul class="sub_sub_menu ">
        <li class=" ">
          <a href="" title="Test Page"><span>Test Page</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dir ">
    <a href="" title="Our Products" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Our Products</span></a>
    <div class="sub_menu">
      <ul class="sub_sub_menu ">
        <li class=" ">
          <a href="" title="Test Products"><span>Test Products</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class=" ">
    <a href="" title="News"><span>News</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Produces the following result when Home is on focus.
[image]

If what you really want are hover events,

- replace 'focusin' with 'mouseover'
- replace 'focusout' with 'mouseout'

Comment: Hello Lucretius,

If home is on focus, I want the div.sub_menu to add style

Comment: Example updated with a `focusin` and `focusout` approach for adding and removing classes as focus changes.  Just a heads up, `hover` and `focus` are different events. Have a look at the answer and see how navigating the dom can be done, up and down.